# sha1 different in go than in python and openssl

Tags: python, encryption, go, openssl, sha1

I am trying to build a base64 encoded sha1 hash in go but the result i am getting is very different to the results of other programming languages

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    c := sha1.New()
  input := []byte("hello")
  myBytes := c.Sum(input)
  fmt.Println(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(base64.StdPadding))
}
```

This Go Code prints out `aGVsbG/aOaPuXmtLDTJVv++VYBiQr9gHCQ==`

My Python Code Looks like this

```
import hashlib
import base64


print(base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1('hello').digest()))
```

And outputs `qvTGHdzF6KLavt4PO0gs2a6pQ00=`

My bash command for comparison looks like this

```
echo -n hello| openssl dgst -sha1 -binary |base64
```

And outputs this `qvTGHdzF6KLavt4PO0gs2a6pQ00=`

Which lets me assume that the python code is doing everything correct.
But why does go prints another result.
Where is my mistake?

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [example](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha1/#New) of how to use it properly. You should do:

```
c := sha1.New()
io.WriteString(c, "hello")
myBytes := c.Sum(nil)
fmt.Println(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(myBytes))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/sELsWTcrdd

Comment: awesome! Yea stupid mistake of mine. But thnx for your quick reply. i ll mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 10):

You use the standard lib in a completely wrong way. Don't assume what a method / function does, always read the docs if it's new to you.

[`sha1.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha1/#New) returns a [`hash.Hash`](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash). Its `Sum()` method is **not** to calculate the hash value, but to get the current hash result,  it does not change the underlying hash state.

`hash.Hash` implements [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer), and to calculate the hash of some data, you have to write that data into it. `Hash.Sum()` takes an optional slice if you already have one allocated, to write the result (the hash) to it. Pass `nil` if you want it to allocate a new one.

Also `base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString()` expects the byte data (byte slice) you want to convert to base64, so you have to pass the checksum data to it. In your code you didn't tell `EncodeToString()` what to encode.

Working example:

```
c := sha1.New()
input := []byte("hello")
c.Write(input)
sum := c.Sum(nil)
fmt.Println(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(sum))
```

Output is as expected (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DJARC5KI4c)):

```
qvTGHdzF6KLavt4PO0gs2a6pQ00=
```

Note that the [`crypto/sha1`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha1/) package also has a handy [`sha1.Sum()`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha1/#Sum) function which does this in one step:

```
input := []byte("hello")
sum := sha1.Sum(input)
fmt.Println(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(sum[:]))
```

Output is the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jXJC66m_SS).